# How to interface RF96W with Stm32F030 based controllers?

Tags: stm32, spi, lora, stm32f0

I have tested my RF96W [LoRa](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/8/0/4/RFM95_96_97_98W.pdf) boards with the [Lolin](https://components101.com/development-boards/nodemcu-esp8266-pinout-features-and-datasheet) Boards, it is working fine, But when I started to interface these Lora boards with stm32f030r8t6 based controller, I cant receive any data. Though I have tried to kept SPI configuration according to Lolin boards.
Board Wiring is same as SPI requirements.

Lolin working Code:

```c
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RH_RF95.h>

#define RFM95_CS 15
#define RFM95_RST 16
#define RFM95_INT 5

RH_RF95 rf95(RFM95_CS, RFM95_INT);

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) ; // Wait for serial port to be available

  rf95.setModemConfig(RH_RF95::Bw125Cr48Sf4096);
  while (!rf95.init()) {
    Serial.println("LoRa radio init failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Sending to rf95_server");
  uint8_t data[] = "Hello World!";
  rf95.send(data, sizeof(data));
  
  rf95.waitPacketSent();
  // Now wait for a reply
  uint8_t buf[RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
  uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);

  if (rf95.waitAvailableTimeout(3000)) { 
    // Should be a reply message for us now   
    if (rf95.recv(buf, &len)) {
      Serial.print("got reply: ");
      Serial.println((char*)buf);
//      Serial.print("RSSI: ");
//      Serial.println(rf95.lastRssi(), DEC);    
    } else {
      Serial.println("recv failed");
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("No reply, is rf95_server running?");
  }
//  delay(400);
}
```

STM32F030R8T6 Controller not working code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <RF95.h>

uint8_t init_failed = 0;
uint8_t Tx_buff[] = "Hello World!";
uint8_t Rx_buff[RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
uint8_t rssi_value = 0;
uint16_t len = 0;

void SystemClock_Config(void);

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
//  RF95_setModemConfig(Bw125Cr48Sf4096);
    if(!RF95_Init()) {
        init_failed = 1;
    }
  while (1) {
//    RF95_send(Tx_buff);
//    RF95_waitPacketSent();
//    if(RF95_available_Timeout(3000)){
//        RF95_receive(Rx_buff);
//    }
      if (RF95_available()) {
          if (RF95_receive(Rx_buff)) {
              len = sizeof(Rx_buff);
          }
          if (len) {
              uint8_t data[] = "And hello back to you";
              RF95_send(data);
              RF95_waitPacketSent();
          }
      }
  }
}
```

For Lolin board [library](https://github.com/adafruit/RadioHead) is also from GitHub.
For ST I'm using RFM95 [library](https://github.com/MartiGeek17/LoRa-RFM95-STM32) from GitHub.

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code, I don't see how we should help you. Information about how you have wired the board and more details about what's working and what is not working would also be helpful.

Comment: What's with the commented lines in non-working code? If you remove RF96W hardware, and just put a jumper on MISO/MOSI - does SPI work then?

Comment: Commented lines are just for changing the device to transmitter or receiver. As of right now non working code is receiver code, to make it transmitter you have uncomment the previous four lines and comment below 7 lines.